# "_doc" in elasticsearch 6.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I was following elasticsearch guide for version 6.0:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html

1] To create mapping

PUT /twitter

```
{
  "mappings": {
    " **_doc** ": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "type": "keyword" }, 
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "user_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "email": { "type": "keyword" },
        "content": { "type": "text" },
        "tweeted_at": { "type": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2] To create document.

PUT twitter/**_doc**/user-kimchy

```
{
  "type": "user", 
  "name": "Shay Banon",
  "user_name": "kimchy",
  "email": "shay@kimchy.com"
}
```

What is "_doc" in 1 and 2 ? considering the fact that types are going away from Elasticsearch 6.0.0

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until ES 8.x there will still be an explicit mapping type per index, even though only a single type will be allowed. You are free to choose whatever name you want for that single type, though, but it is advised to use the dummy  `_doc` (preferred) or `doc` type.

Starting with ES 8, types will disappear completely. You can read more about the [full schedule](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types) planned between ES 5 and 9 to make the removal completely effective.